# How can I upgrade my Dell mini from version 8.04?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, dell

I have a Dell mini with version 8.04. I can not figure out how to upgrade it to any version of Ubuntu I have bought. I can not even boot from a disc. The upgrade manager tries, but always fails. My system works great. You might say if it works, leave it alone, but still why not?

Comment: so what happens if you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and what happens if you follow the 8.04 to 10.04 upgrade advice here?: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades

Comment: Do you have a mini 9 or 10? Can you post the outputs of the following two commands: `lspci`, `uname -m`. Please add the outputs to the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the Dell Mini 9 which came pre-loaded with 8.04 from Dell which was a customized image to fit the small SSD.

There is a very good answer on Ubuntu Forums that should help you fix the issue but to summarize;

> Issues to bear in mind:
>
> 1. The original Dell Ubuntu 8.04 was an "lpia" version, which is no longer supported on 10.04.
> 2. Dell Ubuntu 8.04 uses a special Dell / lpia repository, which does not have USB "Startup Disk Creator"
> 3. Dell Ubuntu 8.04 has proprietary Fluendo codecs for mp3 etc.
>
> What this means to you:
>
> 1. You can't upgrade by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
> 2. You can't create a USB bootable image on your Mini
> 3. You may want to consider backing up your codecs to reinstall after a fresh install of 10.04:
>      http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.p...09#post9224709 (I didn't do
>      this myself - but apparently it does work)
>
> So - how do you actually achieve the upgrade (fresh install)?
>
> 1. Backup your files you want to keep, or just backup the entire /home directory to restore if you want to keep all application settings etc.
> 2. Backup fluendo codecs, if you want to (see above).
> 3. Create a bootable USB startup disk from your iso you downloaded using any other computer (i.e. not your Mini). Or from [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
> 4. Turn off Mini, and plug bootable USB in.
> 5. Press 0 on the first boot screen after turning Mini on and select USB as boot device.
> 6. Follow instructions to install...
> 7. Restore files or /home and/or codecs as you wish.
> 8. Restore wifi with: http://www.ubuntumini.com/2010/04/br...-in-lucid.html

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497176)